# function to find length of 2d string array in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Is there any inbuilt function in cpp that can give me the length of a 2d char array

for ex, the function for args

```
const char* args[] = {"412", "..7", ".58", "7.8", "32.", "6..", "351", "3.9", "985", "...", ".46"}
```

should return 11

Comment: There is no actual function, since using an array as a function parameter causes it to decay to a pointer.  The macros given in the answers can be used in the array's scope.

Comment: @David: arrays don't decay if you pass by reference.

Comment: If you want to do something like that in an idiomatic C++ program, it's more like `std::vector<std::string>` rather than a `char *args[]`.  That way, you do get functions that work.

Comment: Even though the question is narrowly focused on 2d string array, the answer by R. Martinho Fernandes has much wider application to arrays in general.  How about editing the title to ask the general question "Function to find length of array in C++?" so the question can be voted up and get more exposure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give the number of elements in `args`:

```
sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0])
```

Comment: And I'd note that even if you go for one of the other new-fangled ways listed, you should remember this idiom as you'll come across it in a ton of old C++ and C code.

Answer (score 7):

I like to [use a template function](http://ideone.com/ruKX3) for this.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t size(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```

The advantage over an approach using `sizeof` is that you can't accidentally do it with a pointer.

Comment: Bah, you and your fancy template stuff :)

Comment: +1 Specifically, this version fails to compile when passed a pointer. The alternative, `sizeof A/sizeof A[0]`, returns the wrong number when passed a pointer. Failing to compile is always better than giving the wrong answer.

Comment: I tried 
`sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]);`
and it works :)
I didn't want to go for templates, I don't know how to Initialize a 2d string array in them.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use:

```
std::end(args) - std::begin(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(args) / sizeof(*args)`